# How can i use flask-admin in fastapi?

Tags: python, fastapi, flask-admin

I am trying to use flask-admin in fast api. I created two apps (fastapi and flask) but i do not know what do next.

```
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

fastapi_app = FastAPI()

fastapi_app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

engine = create_engine('##################################')
db = Session(engine)

admin = Admin(flask_app, template_mode='bootstrap4')
admin.add_view(ModelView(Users, db))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Rooms, db))
admin.add_view(ModelView(UsersToRooms, db))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Maps, db))

fastapi_app.mount("/admin", admin)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: 'Admin' object is not callable
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/ ? You can't just mount a Flask app under a FastAPI app with `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in case someone needs an answer, the following worked for me:

When mounting the app with fast_api.app.mount, not the Admin class instance but the app attribute of that instance has to be passed to mount()

For the above example:

```
fastapi_app.mount("/admin", admin.app)
```

instead of

```
fastapi_app.mount("/admin", admin)
```